# Page jumps and separate pages in primary navigation

Tags: navigation, header, anchors

We're working on a website and I was wondering what the best practice for this scenario is. We are designing a website for our company and we aren't too sure if it's good practice to link to separate pages as well as linking to page jumps in the same menu.

I have a feeling that it will more than likely confuse the user that they might be going to a different page or to certain points on the same page. Has anyone else had any experience doing this?

Comment: Yes - redirect without opening new page it's good practise. User always can return. It's depends on circumstances (for example if you link to outer webservice/page it can open in new page)

Comment: Sorry I must have worded my question wrong, I was talking about linking to headers on pages from the primary menu (Page Jumping). Some links would be like this, some would be linking to completely different pages on the website.

Comment: Do you link to the another places on a subpage or other subpages?
Do i understand well?

Answer (score 1):

Your main menu on the top of the application should link to the primary title to which it relates.

Links to items within articles can, indeed, link to an item within a page.

This is fairly common practise.

Answer (score 1):

The primary menu is always as a convention used for providing navigation to different webpages within a website. Although, sometimes it is also used for navigation to a specific part of the webpage. A good example would be the Contact menu which sometimes opens a new page or navigates to the bottom of the same page showing the contact details.
I would suggest to avoid having links for within a page on the primary menu.

If there are many sections in the webpage which you want to provide a link for the readers to easily jump to different sections you might want to have something like a floating/sticky widget which shows up on a side providing quick links for within the page. See example here : https://images.app.goo.gl/SmxH4RUko1zZFhdg9